Ignoring prepended content; prependContent can't be used in a Shiny render call
I have a shiny app with lots of points that need to be selected to display data in a table. I love the functionality displayed in this question here. Unfortunately implementing this in shiny produces the error message Ignoring prepended content; prependContent can't be used in a Shiny render call. My shiny app is rather large and requires internal data so I will post the example from the above linked question. If someone can get this working in shiny I can adapt it to my app.
library(leaflet)
library(crosstalk)
library(DT)
library(dplyr)
library(htmltools)
library(summarywidget)

data_2 <- data.frame(ID=c(1:8),
                     Name1 = c("A", "A", "A", "C", "B", "B", "A", "B"),
                     Name2 = c("a", "b", "b", "a", "b", "a", "b", "c"),
                     Value1 = c(12,43,54,34,23,77,44,22),
                     Value2 = c(6,5,2,7,5,6,4,3),
                     Lat = c(51.1, 51.6, 57.3, 52.4, 56.3, 54.3, 60.4, 49.2),
                     Lon = c(5, -3, -2, -1, 4, 3, -5, 0))

data_2<-data_2 %>%
  mutate(
    lab_DB = case_when(
      Name1 == unique(data_2$Name1)[1]  ~ "blue",
      Name1 == unique(data_2$Name1)[2]  ~ "green",
      Name1 == unique(data_2$Name1)[3]  ~  "red"
      
    )
  )


sdf <- SharedData$new(data_2, key=~ID, group="SharedDataqwertyui")


lmap <- leaflet() %>%
  addTiles() %>%
  addMarkers(data=sdf, group="test", layerId = ~ID) %>%
  htmlwidgets::prependContent(tags$script(src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet-lasso@2.2.4/dist/leaflet-lasso.umd.min.js")) %>%
  htmlwidgets::onRender("
    function(el, x) {

      var sheet = window.document.styleSheets[0];
      sheet.insertRule('.selectedMarker { filter: hue-rotate(135deg); }', sheet.cssRules.length);

      var map = this;
      const lassoControl = L.control.lasso(options={'position':'topleft'}).addTo(map);

      function resetSelectedState() {
            map.eachLayer(layer => {
                if (layer instanceof L.Marker) {
                    layer.setIcon(new L.Icon.Default());
                } else if (layer instanceof L.Path) {
                    layer.setStyle({ color: '#3388ff' });
                }
            });
        }
        function setSelectedLayers(layers) {
            resetSelectedState();
            let ids = [];

            layers.forEach(layer => {
                if (layer instanceof L.Marker) {
                  layer.setIcon(new L.Icon.Default({ className: 'selected selectedMarker'}));
                } else if (layer instanceof L.Path) {
                    layer.setStyle({ color: '#ff4620' });
                }

                ids.push(layer.options.layerId);



            });
            ct_filter.set(ids);
        }


        var ct_filter = new crosstalk.FilterHandle('SharedDataqwertyui');
        ct_filter.setGroup('SharedDataqwertyui');

        var ct_sel = new crosstalk.SelectionHandle('SharedDataqwertyui');
        ct_sel.setGroup('SharedDataqwertyui');


        map.on('mousedown', () => {
            ct_filter.clear();
            ct_sel.clear();
            resetSelectedState();
        });
        map.on('lasso.finished', event => {
            setSelectedLayers(event.layers);
        });

        lassoControl.setOptions({ intersect: true});

        var clearSel = function(){
            ct_filter.clear();
            ct_sel.clear();
            resetSelectedState();
        }

        document.getElementById('clearbutton').onclick = clearSel;
    }") %>%
  addEasyButton(
    easyButton(
      icon = "fa-ban",
      title = "Clear Selection",
      id="clearbutton",
      onClick = JS("function(btn, map){
              return
         }")
    )
  ) 


dtable <- datatable(sdf , width = "100%",editable=TRUE, caption=tags$caption("Mean of Value1: ",summarywidget(sdf, statistic='mean', column='Value1')))

bscols( widths=c(6,6,0), lmap, dtable, htmltools::p(summarywidget(sdf, statistic='mean', column='Value1'), style="display:none;"))


Did you check this question and its answer?

Yes I saw that. It looked tmap specific. I don't think that will work in my case but please prove me wrong.

You could implement the lasso selection which is given by the example in your question in shiny as shown below.

library(shiny)
library(leaflet)
library(crosstalk)
library(dplyr)
library(htmltools)

lassoPlugin <- htmlDependency(
  "Leaflet.lasso",
  "2.2.13",
  src = c(href = "https://unpkg.com/leaflet-lasso@2.2.13/dist/"),
  script = "leaflet-lasso.umd.min.js"
)

registerPlugin <- function(map, plugin) {
  map$dependencies <- c(map$dependencies, list(plugin))
  map
}

data_2 <- data.frame(
  ID = c(1:8),
  Name1 = c("A", "A", "A", "C", "B", "B", "A", "B"),
  Name2 = c("a", "b", "b", "a", "b", "a", "b", "c"),
  Value1 = c(12, 43, 54, 34, 23, 77, 44, 22),
  Value2 = c(6, 5, 2, 7, 5, 6, 4, 3),
  Lat = c(51.1, 51.6, 57.3, 52.4, 56.3, 54.3, 60.4, 49.2),
  Lon = c(5, -3, -2, -1, 4, 3, -5, 0)
)

data_2 <- data_2 %>%
  mutate(lab_DB = case_when(
    Name1 == unique(data_2$Name1)[1]  ~ "blue",
    Name1 == unique(data_2$Name1)[2]  ~ "green",
    Name1 == unique(data_2$Name1)[3]  ~  "red"
  ))

sdf <- SharedData$new(data_2, key =  ~ ID, group = "SharedDataqwertyui")

ui <- fluidPage(leafletOutput("map"))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$map <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet() %>%
      addTiles() %>%
      addMarkers(data = sdf,
                 group = "test",
                 layerId = ~ ID) %>%
      registerPlugin(lassoPlugin) %>%
      htmlwidgets::onRender("
        function(el, x) {

          setTimeout(() => {
            var sheet = window.document.styleSheets[0];
            sheet.insertRule('.selectedMarker { filter: hue-rotate(135deg); }', sheet.cssRules.length);

            var map = this;
            const lassoControl = L.control.lasso(options={'position':'topleft'}).addTo(map);

            function resetSelectedState() {
              map.eachLayer(layer => {
                if (layer instanceof L.Marker) {
                  layer.setIcon(new L.Icon.Default());
                } else if (layer instanceof L.Path) {
                  layer.setStyle({ color: '#3388ff' });
                }
              });
            }
            function setSelectedLayers(layers) {
              resetSelectedState();
              let ids = [];

              layers.forEach(layer => {
                if (layer instanceof L.Marker) {
                  layer.setIcon(new L.Icon.Default({ className: 'selected selectedMarker'}));
                } else if (layer instanceof L.Path) {
                  layer.setStyle({ color: '#ff4620' });
                }

                ids.push(layer.options.layerId);
              });
              ct_filter.set(ids);
            }

            var ct_filter = new crosstalk.FilterHandle('SharedDataqwertyui');
            ct_filter.setGroup('SharedDataqwertyui');

            var ct_sel = new crosstalk.SelectionHandle('SharedDataqwertyui');
            ct_sel.setGroup('SharedDataqwertyui');

            map.on('mousedown', () => {
                ct_filter.clear();
                ct_sel.clear();
                resetSelectedState();
            });

            map.on('lasso.finished', event => {
                setSelectedLayers(event.layers);
            });

            lassoControl.setOptions({ intersect: true});

            var clearSel = function(){
                ct_filter.clear();
                ct_sel.clear();
                resetSelectedState();
            }

            document.getElementById('clearbutton').onclick = clearSel;

          }, '50');
        }"
      ) %>%
      addEasyButton(
        easyButton(
          icon = "fa-ban",
          title = "Clear Selection",
          id = "clearbutton",
          onClick = JS("function(btn, map){
              return
         }")
        )
      )
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)


Excellent, this works. I was able to add to server output$map_select_table <- renderDataTable({     datatable(sdf , width = "100%",editable=TRUE)},server=FALSE) and now I have a table in shiny that talks with the lasso. Thanks and Cheers!
